# Help with a physics problem about the magnetic field

Tags: physics, electromagnetism

Text of the problem:
A circular loop of radius $R$ carries a current $I_1$. Perpendicular to the plane of the coil, and tangent to it, there is an indefinite rectilinear wire, traversed by a current $I_2$. Calculate the magnetic field $B$ at the centre of the coil.
The data of the problem are $R,I_1,I_2$.

So I understand the fact that the magnetic field of the wire is taken by the Biot-savart law and the magnetic field of the loop is $\mu_0i\over2R$, but in the solution (that is not well-explained) they use the Pythagorean theorem ($\sqrt{ B_1^2+B_2^2}$) to calculate the Magnetic field at the centre of the loop.

Comment: The magnetic field vectors are perpendicular (at $90º$) at the centre and hence to find their combined magnitude one uses the pythagorean theorem. Assume that the magnetic field vectors complete a right angled triangle, then the hypotenuse is their combined magnitude.

Comment: Not just the solution isn't well-explained, also the problem. a) A loop isn't a coil. b) The wire isn't tangent to the loop, it just touches the loop. The tangent to the loop lies in the plane of the loop (to which the wire is perpendicular).

Comment: @joriki (+1) I completely agree.  The problem is not well-expalined at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple diagram of how the scenario is suggested:

[image: Scenario Image]

Where the the $\color{red}{\bigcirc}$ represent the direction of current flow in the rectilinear wire. Beforehand, $$\bigcirc = \text{direction out of the diagram} \\ \times= \text{direction into the diagram}$$

I assume that I have predicted the directions of the magnetic fields correctly, using the direction of current. Nonetheless, they do not affect calculations of the magnitude of combined magnetic field.

The combined magnetic field at **centre of the coil** is the magnetic field generated by the coil and the magnetic field at point $Q$ combined.

If we were to rotate to the plane of the rectilinear wire, we can see that magnetic field vectors are at $90º$ to each other:

[image: Plane of wire; Magnetic field vectors]

To calculate the combined magnitude we shift one vector to the head of the other, and hence we can apply the pythagorean theorem.

[image: Re-arranged vector diagram]

Hence, we have $$\color{blue}{||B_T||} = \sqrt{\color{red}{||B||^2} + \color{black}{||B||^2}}$$